# too many redirects EE 2.5.4

Tags: htaccess, redirects, .htaccess

I have moved the site www.webawards.com.au and followed the information in regards to moving the existing site to a new server.
I have a problem with too many 302 redirects and the hosting company says it is not them.
I have a modified HBP5 .htaccess file. I have commented out different sections of the rewrite engine rules and tested these to no avail. 
here is the code I have used for the rewrites.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# (1)
RewriteEngine On

# (2)
Options +FollowSymlinks

# (3)
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# (4)
RewriteBase /

# (5)
# RewriteOptions <options>

# (6)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]

</IfModule>

# Option 2: rewrite example.com → www.example.com
#
# Be aware that the following might not be a good idea if you use "real"
# subdomains for certain parts of your website.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
   RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Forcing `https://`                                                 |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Redirect from the `http://` to the `https://` version of the URL.
# https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything in the version of EE I am using that would cause the redirects. I am at a loss as to what it can be. It happens when ever I save or submit a change via control panel and it is also happening to people who are entering the awards and saving their entries.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take it back to basics *note* I'm no htaccess guru, heres my personal https file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# Option 1:
# Rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried the above and it worked for a couple of things I do in admin and then when I looked at a template, edited it then update and finish, I got the too many redirects error again.